# How to identify all tables and columns in a PLSQL stored procedure SQL file?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, dependencies

I have a very large (~7800 lines) .SQL file which contains stored procedures written in PL/SQL.

I am not able to connect to the database, so I can only parse it locally with text editors.

How would I be able to identify and extract all of the tables, columns, and dependencies in it?

I have python and cx_Oracle. I have been reading the documentation for cx_Oracle, but don't know where I would begin, and if that would even help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with cx_Oracle since it is a module for database access...

Comment: Is this a one-off task or something you need to do regularly?  What do you want to do with the information?